# Modified Euclidean topology by rationals is not $T_3$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ the topological space with the topology $\tau$ a basis of which is given from

$\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b),\quad a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b\} \quad \cup \quad \{\{q\},\quad q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

I've proved easily that $X$ is second countable.

Now I try to prove that $X$ is not $T_3$ and I think to show a counterexample of a point and a closed set that are non-separable with two open sets, but I'm stuck.

I think this way:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}$ and consider $U$ an open neighborhood of $x$. Then, exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subseteq U$. Now, for the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, exists $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x-\epsilon<q<x+\epsilon$. But, $\{q\}$ is a closed set cointained in every open set that cointains $x$, so it's a closed set that can't be separated from $x$ with two open disjointed sets.

Could this make sense?

Comment: Hint: is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{q\}$ closed?

Comment: Is my edit almost correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your argument does not work because $\{q\}$ is not contained in ***every*** open set that contains $x$, it is instead contained in a ***particular*** open set containing $x$.

More to the point, what you are trying to prove is not true; $\tau$ is indeed $T_3$.

To see this, note first that $\tau$ is stronger than the Euclidean topology, so is certainly $T_1$.  It remains to show $\tau$ is regular.

Therefore, consider $x\in X$ and closed $C\subset X$, with $x\notin C$.

If $x\in \mathbb Q$, then $\{x\}$ is open and closed, hence $X\backslash \{x\}$ is open and closed, hence $\{x\}$ and $X\backslash \{x\}$ are disjoint open sets separating $x$ and $C$.

If $x\notin \mathbb Q$, then since $X\backslash C$ is open, there is a basis element $B\in \mathcal B$ with $x\in B\subseteq X\backslash C$.  Since $x\notin \mathbb Q$, we have $B=(a,b)\ni x$ for some $a<b$.  Choosing $a',a'',b',b''$ with $a<a'<a''<x<b''<b'<b$, we have  $x\in (a'',b'')=:U$, $C\subseteq X \backslash [a',b']=:V$.  Then $U$ and $V$ are open in $\tau$, disjoint, and separate $x$ and $C$.