# Modified euclidean compact intervals as elements of a basis

Tags: general-topology

Let

$$\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b], \quad a,b\in \mathbb{Q}, a<b\} \cup \{\{q\},\quad q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

a family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and be $\tau$ the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ that has $\mathcal{B}$ as a basis.

Establish whether the topological space $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is

a) connected.

b) compact.

c) locally compact.

d) metrizable.

e) a Baire space.

I've found that:

a) $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is not connected. For example, the subset $(1,2)$ is open because

$$(1,2)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left[1+\frac{1}{n+1},2-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]$$

and its complement is the subset

$$\mathbb{R}\setminus (1,2) = (-\infty, 1] \cup [2,+\infty) = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [-n,1] \cup \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N},n>2} [2,n]$$

which is open too.

So, $(1,2)$ is a clopen subset of $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$.

I think that even $\{q\}$ with $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ works as a clopen subset.

b) From the point a) we can find that $\tau$ is finer than the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so, we can conclude that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

c) For the argument used in point b), we have to take at least a compact euclidean neighborhood. In particular, let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\{x\}$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$ because is open and finite.

If $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, any neighborhood of ${x}$ contains $[a_x,b_x]$ for some $a_x,b_x\in\mathbb{Q}, a_x<b_x$.
I suspect that this neighborhood is not compact and so the space is not locally compact, but I can't formalize the proof.

d) I've proved that $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is $T_3$. Moreover, $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is clearly 2-countable and so, thanks to the Urysohn's metrizability theorem, $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is metrizable.

e) I've no idea how to prove that. If $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is not locally compact (if it is right proved in the previous points), how can I prove or disprove this fact?

Any suggestions for the incomplete parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just let me remark that for a), you are correct about rational singletons being clopen, as they are open as members of the basis, and are closed since the topology is stronger than the Euclidean topology.

For c), as you have noticed, any neighborhood of $x\in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ must contain an interval $[a,b]$.  Let $q\in (a,b)\cap \mathbb Q$.  Then $\{q+\frac{1}{n}\}$ eventually lies in $[a,b]$, but has no convergent subsequence (since the topology is stronger than the Euclidean topology, a convergent subsequence could only converge to $q$, but $q$ is isolated.)  Therefore no neighborhood of an irrational can be sequentially compact, and since $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ (and its subsets) are metrizable by d), we conclude that no neighborhood of an irrational is compact.

Regarding e), note that a set has interior if and only if it contains at least one rational.  Therefore, *any* union of sets with no interior still has no interior.  This is much stronger than the Baire condition, which only requires that a countable union of closed sets with no interior has no interior.  Thus $X$ is indeed a Baire space.

Comment: Ok, but for a) is correct that $(1,2)$ is clopen?

Comment: @SigmaAlgebra yes that works as well.

Comment: In general, everything you have said that I didn't remark upon looks fine.

Comment: Ok good. To prove that the space is $T3$ I used a similar argument of the reasons because euclidean $\mathbb{R}$ is $T3$, does it sound good for you?

Comment: @SigmaAlgebra probably, it really is the same as the argument from this answer that you asked about awhile ago https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4831404/1210477 - despite the fact that the basis is slightly different, its the same topology as this question.

Comment: I repeated the same reasoning you suggested by adjusting the brackets to obtain open sets in this topology, do you think it's enough?

Comment: @SigmaAlgebra it's really impossible to critique without looking at what you actually wrote specifically for your argument, though my hunch is its probably fine.

Comment: I wrote the same identical argument choosing $a',a'',b',b''\in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a<a'<a''<x<b''<b'<b$ and defining $X\setminus (a',b')$ as the open set that contains the closed set $C$ and $[a'',b'']$ as the open set that contains $x$

Comment: @SigmaAlgebra that looks fine.